# How can I debug EXC_BAD_ACC (code=2, address=xxx)?

Tags: ios, swift, crash, exc-bad-access

When I try to run my app, I keep getting a crash named "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee5fe2f08)". (The address can vary from crash to crash.)

I don't know how to solve this problem. Every suggestion I stumbled upon did not solve my problem. I tried the "Runtime sanitation", both the address sanitizer and the thread sanitizer. I also tried enabling zombie objects. I tried rewriting and rewiring my classes, labels and objects. I tried deleting the code that the error message appears next to – but then, in the next run, the message just pops up somewhere else, seemingly random. Nothing helped so far. I'm new to programming: Last time I had this error, I eventually rebuilt the app from scratch – that helped. (I really don't wanna keep solving my problems like that.)

What did I do wrong, how can I fix this, and how can I prevent this from happening again in the future?

**Update:** It seems to be a problem about the [.init(frame:)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPQKj.png) The subject (In this case the "HabitCellButton") varies from crash to crash, but the .init(frame:) stays the same. Still, no idea how to solve this problem.

[This is an example of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r390.png)

[Closer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDrEA.png)

Here's my HabitsViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class HabitsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let totalWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let mainButtonTrailingLeading: CGFloat = CGFloat(34)
let distanceSuperViewCollectionViewCell: CGFloat = CGFloat(149)

let reuseIdentifier = "cell"
var habitArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

@IBOutlet weak var habitsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var daysLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var enterHabit: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var addNewHabitLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var plusButton: PlusButton!

let indexPrepare = IndexPrepare()
let plusButtonExtension = PlusButton()
let moreButtonExtension = MoreButton()
let cellButtonExtension = HabitCellButton()
let moreVC = MoreViewController()
let habitCellVC = HabitCell()
let habitsViewController = HabitsViewController()

// Screen width.
public var screenWidth: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
}

// Screen height.
public var screenHeight: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}

// Telling the CollectionView how many cells to make.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return habitArray.count
}

// Making a cell for each cell index path.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HabitCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.cellLabel.text = habitArray[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 256/256, green: 256/256, blue: 256/256, alpha: 1.0)

    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 111/256, green: 111/256, blue: 110/256, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 111/256, green: 111/256, blue: 110/256, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    // cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: totalWidth - 2*mainButtonTrailingLeading, height: 68.5)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: distanceSuperViewCollectionViewCell, left: mainButtonTrailingLeading, bottom: 34, right: mainButtonTrailingLeading)
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Optical setup
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 253/256, green: 253/256, blue: 253/256, alpha: 1.0)
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 253/256, green: 253/256, blue: 253/256, alpha: 1.0)

    indexPrepare.weekDaySetup(daysLabel: daysLabel)

    indexPrepare.habitsLabelOptic(habitsLabel: habitsLabel)

    indexPrepare.daysLabelOptic(daysLabel: daysLabel)

    plusButtonExtension.pGenerator.prepare()

    moreButtonExtension.mGenerator.prepare()

    cellButtonExtension.cGenerator.prepare()

    enterHabit.isHidden = true

    if habitArray.count != 0 {
        addNewHabitLabel.isHidden = true
    }
    else if habitArray.count == 0 {
        addNewHabitLabel.isHidden = false
    }
}

@IBAction func plusButtonPressed(_ sender: PlusButton) {
    sender.animatePlusButton()

    if addNewHabitLabel.isHidden == false {
        if addNewHabitLabel.text != "" {
            UIView.transition(with: addNewHabitLabel,
                 duration: 0.15,
                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
               animations: { [weak self] in
                self?.addNewHabitLabel.text = (arc4random() % 1 == 0) ? "" : "Two"
            }, completion: nil)
        }

        else if addNewHabitLabel.text == "" {
            addNewHabitLabel.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    enterHabit.isHidden = false

    // collectionViewSwift.textFieldShouldReturn(enterHabit)
    // [myTextField becomeFirstRespoder];
}

@IBAction func morePressed(_ sender: MoreButton) {
    sender.animateMoreButton()
}

@IBAction func returnFromSegueActions(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
}
```

Here's my PlusButton class:

```
import UIKit

class PlusButton: UIButton {
let pGenerator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()

func animatePlusButton() {
    pGenerator.notificationOccurred(.success)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.06, delay: 0.0,
        animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.80, y: 0.80)
        },
        completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.12) {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
        }
    )
}

override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let newArea = CGRect(
        x: self.bounds.origin.x - 5.0,
        y: self.bounds.origin.y - 5.0,
        width: self.bounds.size.width + 20.0,
        height: self.bounds.size.height + 20.0
    )
    return newArea.contains(point)
}

}
```

Comment: You know how to use the Xcode debugger? It shows you which function the crash is in, you can look at variable values etc. You posted the one bit of information that I wouldn't even look at.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks! That did it. The debugger seemed to circle back to the beginning everytime it came to the line that declared "let habitsViewController = HabitsViewController()". So I deleted that line. It works now and I am infinitely relieved.